# For /f command output return nothing

Tags: batch-file

Why is that I'm getting an empty result on the batch i try make below:

```
@echo off


 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


rem empty recycle bin
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic USERACCOUNT where name="%username%" get sid"') do (
   if not "%%a"=="SID" (          
      set myvar=%%a
   )   
)


cd %systemdrive%\$Recycle.Bin\!myvar!

echo The directory is change to %systemdrive%\$Recycle.Bin\!myvar!
pause
```

it doesn't show the value of myvar

Comment: may be you need one additional for loop like here : https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266

Comment: `myvar` is either not being set or it is being cleared.  What is your wmic command returning?  Have you tried replacing the loop body with an `echo %%a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your script fixed:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem Empty recycle bin
For /F "Skip=1" %%A In ('WMIC UserAccount Where "Name='%UserName%'"^
 Get SID 2^>Nul') Do For %%B In (%%A) Do Set "MyVar=%%B"
CD /D "%SystemDrive%\$Recycle.Bin\%MyVar%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Echo The directory has been changed to %CD%
Pause
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir, but can you explain to me those 2>Nul and 2^>Nul. 
what I know is >Nul is to clear the message?

Comment: Redirection to the `NUL` device has the effect of hiding output. `command 1> NUL` writes standard output, _(STDOUT)_, of `command` to the `NUL` device. The default redirection output operator is `1` which can be, _and usually is_ dropped, `command > NUL`. `command 2> NUL` writes standard error, _(STDERR)_, of `command` to the `NUL` device. In the cases above I used `2> NUL` to redirect possible standard error output away from the screen. Because of priority issues when the `For` command is read, it is necessary to escape the redirector `>` with a caret, `^`, _(the standard escape character)_.